# Emgu CV - Combining greyscale images into single Bgr image

Tags: c#, opencv, emgucv

I'm trying to convert a greyscale image to a Hsv image, but with the S and V channels set to a preset value. The following code works but takes ~400ms to execute.

```
public void ToHueImage(this Image<Gray, double> image, Image<Hsv, double> output)
{
        for (int i = 0; i < image.Width; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < image.Height; j++)
            {
                output.Data[j, i, 0] = image.Data[j, i, 0];
                output.Data[j, i, 1] = 255;
                output.Data[j, i, 2] = 255;
            }
        }           
    }
}
```

I would like to be able to assign a single greyscale image channel to each of the H, S, and V planes in a single operation to avoid copying the pixels across individually, something along the lines of

```
public void ToHueImage(this Image<Gray, double> image, Image<Hsv, double>     output)
{
    output.Data.H = image; 
    output.Data.S = WHITE_IMAGE; // These are static
    output.Data.V = WHITE_IMAGE; // These are static            
}
```

without resorting to byte copying etc. I'm trying to get the execution time to ~30ms or so. Is there any straightforward way to accomplish this?

Comment: Why don't you use `cv::merge` with (your gray image, white image, white image)?

Comment: That's exactly what I needed - just `CvInvoke.Merge(new VectorOfMat(image.Mat, whiteImage.Mat, whiteImage.Mat), heatMap.Mat);`

Comment: Ps set your answer and I'll close it ;-)

Comment: Thanks Miki - would have taken me a while to find that, appreciate it

Comment: @TheMachinist Take some time to read through the documentation of OpenCV, so that you get some idea about what functionality is provided, and where to look for it (especially the fundamentals, such as data structures, and basic array operations). It will help you avoid reinventing the wheel. Especially when you have the inclination to manually iterate over pixels performing the same operation on each of them -- that's a good time to stop, think, and dig through the docs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sorted thanks to Miki: just need to call opencv function merge using CVInvoke:

```
CvInvoke.Merge(new VectorOfMat(image.Mat, whiteImage.Mat, whiteImage.Mat), heatMap.Mat);
```

Comment: If this is the solution to your problem, mark it as solution