# EmguCV C# - merge hsv channels after splitting

Tags: c#, image-processing, opencv3.0, emgucv

With EmguCV Version 3.4.3 in C# I am trying to merge the channels after splitting the hsv image into grayscale channels.

In the future I want to be able to alter the values of the channels separately and than merge them, so I can show the image.

I found `CvInvoke.Merge(channels, output);` but don't know how to get the channels back together so that `CvInvoke.Merge` accepts them as argument.

See my code so far:

```
        Image<Bgr, Byte> imgBrg = new Image<Bgr, Byte>(640, 480);
        capture.Retrieve(imgBrg, 0);
        Image<Hsv, Byte> imgHsv = imgBrg.Convert<Hsv, Byte>();
        pictureBox1.Image = imgHsv.Bitmap;

        Image<Gray, Byte>[] channels = imgHsv.Split();
        Image<Gray, Byte> imghue = channels[0];
        Image<Gray, Byte> imgsat = channels[1];
        Image<Gray, Byte> imgval = channels[2];
        // whats next?
```

Does anyone have a good resource for EmguCV? Actually I find it pretty pretty hard to gain any knowledge on how to use it. Especially since the methods, calls, etc. do have total different naming than in the original c++ lib.
I would switch to the natively supported platforms but my work environment does not allow it.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: CvInvoke.Merge(...

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47700425/5008845

Comment: Big thumbs up @Miki , I didn't found that during my previous searches.