# Emgu CV and IInputArrayOfArrays on Merge() function

Tags: c#, opencv, emgucv

I am struggling to understand what is an `IInputArrayOfArrays`.

It's a bit confusing when you check the docs of OpenCV or EmguCV and most of the functions got `IInputArray` or `IOutputArray` on the function parameters, but with some search you get to know that it means basically a Mat.

But in this case, I thought that a `IInputArrayOfArrays` must be an array of Mat, but this is not working on C#:

```
Mat[] channels = hsv.Split();
channels[1] = customMask;
CvInvoke.Merge(channels, hsv);
```

Because `Can't convert from Emgu.CV.Mat[] to Emgu.CV.IInputArrayOfArrays`.

Since the `Split()` function returns `Mat[]`, it would be logical that the `Merge()` function (that is exactly the opposite of the `Split()`) needs a `Mat[]` also...

Comment: `InputArrayOfArrays`: https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/dc/d84/group__core__basic.html#ga606feabe3b50ab6838f1ba89727aa07a but practically this *should* imply what you understand, namely a vector of Mat (or C# equivalent) -- your problem seems **Emgu-specific**. that wrapper seems to do its own thing, and not adapt C#-native types (arrays) properly. I'd recommend a bug report to Emgu, or to ditch the wrapper and use a different one.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Emgu CV - Combining greyscale images into single Bgr image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47700067/emgu-cv-combining-greyscale-images-into-single-bgr-image)

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz well, in fact I can merge the channels doing this `new VectorOfMat`, but I am still wondering why a `Mat[]` that is the output of the `Split` function, is not a valid input for the `Merge` function, that is just the opposite... I still don't understand why this is not a valid `IInputArrayOfArrays`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pay attention to not confuse `CvInvoke.Split()` and `Mat.Split()`.

Using `Mat.Split()` will return a `Mat[]` but `CvInvoke.Merge()` does not accept that.

Instead, if you use `CvInvoke.Split()` it will return you a `VectorOfVectorOfByte`, the same type that the `CvInvoke.Merge()` method needs, making it exactly the opposite of the `CvInvoke.Split()` indeed.

Here's an example with your case:

```
VectorOfVectorOfByte splitted = new VectorOfVectorOfByte();
CvInvoke.Split(channels, splitted);
// ... //
CvInvoke.Merge(splitted, channels);
```

Comment: You are right, I was confusing both methods. In some way this answers my question, but I still think that is nonsense to `CvInvoke.Merge()` not accepting `Mat[]`...

Comment: I feel you, while playing with Emgu I encountered similar situations, specially with `VectorOf...` and `VectorOfVectorOf...` but once you understand them it's all downhill